# An object inside map function is not recognized

Tags: r, purrr

I have a nested dataframe and I would like to get the numbers of rows which is not NA for each column in the child dataframe as follows (simplified version):

```
df <- list(
  tibble(a=c(1, 2, NA_real_, 4, 5), b=c(2, NA_real_, 5, NA_real_, 3)),
  tibble(a=c(NA_real_, 2, 3, NA_real_, 5), b=c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 1, 3))
) %>%
  tibble(x=1:2, y=.)

res <- df %>%
  mutate(z=map(y, function(dat){
    c(a="a", b="b") %>% map_int(function(col){
      dat %>% filter(!is.na(!!sym(col))) %>% nrow()
    }) %>% enframe()
  }))
```

When I run the code, I get an error that says: `Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols`. It seems that `col` inside the function is not recognized.
Why does this behavior occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is called `df`, you could do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 <- df %>% mutate(res = map(y, ~.x %>% summarise_all(~sum(!is.na(.)))))

df1$res
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      a     b
#  <int> <int>
#1     4     3

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#      a     b
#  <int> <int>
#1     3     2
```

Or using base R :

```
sapply(df$y, function(x) colSums(!is.na(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually I managed to get the result by myself, but yours is much simpler and more efficient than mine :) I really appreciate it.
But I still don't get why my previous code didn't work well. Do you have any idea?

Comment: When you are doing `map(y,...` you are passing the column values and not name. I guess that is the reason to get that error.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't get your answer... I thought the child dataframe `tibble(a=..., b=...)` itself is passed with `map(y, ...`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not really. You are passing only `y` value from `map` which is inside `mutate` statement.

Comment: Um, what do you mean by `y` **value**? I stored dataframes in `y` column, then isn't `y` value the same with dataframe? I'm sorry for my poor understanding...