# An object inside map function is not recognized (another case)

Tags: r, purrr

This question is actually almost a duplicate of my previous question ([An object inside map function is not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61114998/an-object-inside-map-function-is-not-recognized)), but since I encountered a similar problem, I would like to get a precise understanding of this phenomenon.

Suppose I have the following data frame,

```
df <- structure(list(a11 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
                     a12 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
                     a21 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),
                     a22 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
                     b11 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),
                     b12 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
                     b21 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
                     b22 = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)),
                row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and is trying to add four new columns based on combinations of existing columns (ex. `a11` and `b11`).

(Expected output)

```
structure(list(Group11 = c("g1", "g1", "g3", "g3", "g2", "g2", "g1", "g3", "g2", "g3"),
               Group12 = c("g3", "g1", "g4", "g2", "g3", "g1", "g4", "g3", "g1", "g1"),
               Group21 = c("g1", "g2", "g1", "g2", "g3", "g2", "g1", "g3", "g4", "g2"),
               Group22 = c("g3", "g2", "g2", "g1", "g3", "g3", "g4", "g3", "g3", "g3")),
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I first tried this code:

```
1:2 %>% expand_grid(i1=., i2=.) %>% mutate(data=map2(i1, i2, function(i1, i2){
  df %>% transmute(
    !!(str_c("Group", i1, i2)):=if_else(!!sym(str_c("a", i1, i2)),
                                        if_else(!!sym(str_c("b", i1, i2)), "g1", "g2"),
                                        if_else(!!sym(str_c("b", i1, i2)), "g3", "g4"))) %>% return()
})) %>% .$data %>% reduce(bind_cols)
```

and got an error which says: `Error: object 'i1' not found`.

However, if I tried another code as follows,

```
fun_group <- function(i1, i2){
  df %>% transmute(
    !!(str_c("Group", i1, i2)):=if_else(!!sym(str_c("a", i1, i2)),
                                        if_else(!!sym(str_c("b", i1, i2)), "g1", "g2"),
                                        if_else(!!sym(str_c("b", i1, i2)), "g3", "g4"))) %>% return()
}
1:2 %>% expand_grid(i1=., i2=.) %>% mutate(data=map2(i1, i2, fun_group)) %>% .$data %>% reduce(bind_cols)
```

then I successfully got the expected output.

The difference between the two is that I just declared my original function `fun_group` outside `map` function in my second code, but the results are completely different, and I can hardly understand what caused this difference.

I would be grateful if you could let me know the exact mechanism of `map` function that caused these different results.
I am sorry for posting similar question twice, and thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: That's a problem of timing with `!!` injection. By design it happens eagerly when the outermost data-masking function is called. We'll try to fix this in the next major version of rlang: https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/issues/845

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I finally understood the problem thanks to your answers to other related questions. I fully appreciate your efforts to maintain this helpful package!

Answer (score 0):

How about some use of `pmap`. It automatically makes the first column of a data.frame `.x` and the second column `.y`:

```
library(tidyverse)
1:2 %>%
  expand_grid(i1=., i2=.) %>%
  pmap_chr(~str_c(.x,.y)) %>%
  setNames(str_c("Group",.)) %>%
  map_dfc(~ df %>% 
            select(ends_with(.x)) %>%
            pmap_chr(~case_when(.x & .y ~ "g1",
                                .x & !.y ~ "g2",
                                !.x & .y ~ "g3",
                                !.x & !.y ~ "g4",
                                TRUE ~ NA_character_)))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Group11 Group12 Group21 Group22
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
 1 g1      g3      g1      g3     
 2 g1      g1      g2      g2     
 3 g3      g4      g1      g2     
 4 g3      g2      g2      g1     
 5 g2      g3      g3      g3     
 6 g2      g1      g2      g3     
 7 g1      g4      g1      g4     
 8 g3      g3      g3      g3     
 9 g2      g1      g4      g3     
10 g3      g1      g2      g3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is much straight. It would be great if you could let me know why my first code got an error if possible.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but my first guess would be that `fun_group` was defined in the global environment, where `df` exists and thus diffusion with `!!sym()` works. In contrast, the anonymous version is defined in the call stack of `map2`, where `df` is a few levels up in the stack. Thus, diffusion fails. These sorts of hard to pin down behaviors are why I really try to avoid expression diffusion if at all possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I will carefully take a look at the documentation and try to understand.